# how do you include 3rdparty lib/software with your java software?

Tags: java

i am setting up a java project now. in the past, we always included everything (unzipped) from the 3rdparty, such as ant, junit, jfreechart, and others, inside our release. I am wondering is it possible just take those related .jar files but not everything with our software release? then we can get a smaller and neat release. Those 3rdparty library licenses don't allow us to do that way? what's your way? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If their licenses say that you should distribute derivatives with sources, then you are obliged to do that by law.

Another question is if they really force that. As far as I remember GPL, you shall distribute the sources if you want, but there is another way - you must make sources easily availiable to users. So you can drop sources in your distributables.

Any way, you should look at the licenses.

EDIT:

If you will decide to pack the whole program into single jar, I recommend [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). It is java optimiser, shrinker, and much more - all in one! To pack everything into one jar, just specify all your jars - program and libraries - as program jars, and specify only one jar as output. Usually it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to retain the separate jars, if possible. Check out the maven [appassembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) plugin. It does a nice job of putting together an "unzippable" installation for you, in a controlled way. In the result you'll have a very straightforward "repo" directory filled with all of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to build a single jar for each application. The plugin quickly handles the fuss of unzipping all the library jars and putting the whole lot back together as a single jar. It also supports writing a manifest with a main class specified which makes running the application simple from a command line (much simpler than specifying a classpath argument as long as your arm anyway).